# Can I minimize somehow the 7-zip output/log in C#?

Tags: c#, compression, output, 7zip

I am using this code to compress folders:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
                        p.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
                        p.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + item.ToString() + "\" -mx=9";
                        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                        Process x = Process.Start(p);
                        x.WaitForExit();
                        Directory.Delete(dirPath + "\\" + item.Name, true);
```

When the app is compiling I get this output:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Open archive: C:\a\b\folders\compress.7z
--
Path = C:\a\b\folders\compress.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 881619
Headers Size = 273
Method = LZMA2:23
Solid = +
Blocks = 1

    Scanning the drive:
    1 folder, 2 files, 8258668 bytes (8066 KiB)

    Updating archive: C:\a\b\folders\compress.7z

    Add new data to archive: 1 folder, 2 files, 8258668 bytes (8066 KiB)

     60% U Folder\thisisatext.txt
```

But I only want this: `60% U Folder\thisisatext.txt`
Can I do this somehow? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Tip: consider `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating strings when building a path - it handles a lot of edge cases and puts the correct slashes etc in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your process’s standard output to redirect, like so:

`p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`

([read more about this here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8))

You can then read 7 Zips output into a stream reader:

```cs
var reader = x.StandardOutput;
var output = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Now that your programs output is stored in a string you can get your 60% value back. If it is always the last line of the output you could use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to get it:

```cs
var lastLine = output.Split('\n').Last().Trim();
Console.WriteLine(lastLine); // 60% U Folder\\thisisatext.txt"
```

In this case, we are splitting the lines of the output into an array `.Split('\n')` then selecting the last line `.Last()`. We then remove any whitespace that might be before or after the string using `.Trim()`.